# Treating "#" as a regular character when reading data

Tags: r, hashtag

I'm almost certain this has been asked before but due to a certain social media app I drowning in unrelated search results.

So the data set that I'm importing contains actual "#", as in Apartment #404, and I'd like to if possible preserve the character but R thinks it's an end of line or something.  At first it would bomb out on the first occurrence, then I set fill=TRUE and now it just ignores the rest of the line after that.

How does one instruct R to treat #'s as regular characters?

Answer (score 9):

If you are not using "#" as a comment symbol in your data, you can use

```
read.table(..., comment.char="")
```

That should treat "#" like any other character.